# Canvas duplicates multiple shapes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to add 10 to the position of the ball, but it adds position to the duplicated shape. I tried to make a separate function but it did not work.

HTML5 Code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="Game" width="800" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;"></canvas>
 <script src="Game.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>

 Javascript Code:

  var GameCanvas = GameCanvas = document.getElementById("Game");
  var GameCtx = GameCtx = GameCanvas.getContext("2d");;
  var BallSprite = 50;

  window.onload = function () {

  setInterval(HoldSprites, 100);
  }

  function HoldSprites() {
  BallSprite = BallSprite + 10;
    GameCtx.beginPath();
    GameCtx.arc(BallSprite, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    GameCtx.stroke();
    }
```

Comment: You may want to be more clear one what the issue is. Right now you are calling `HoldSprites` every 100ms which is adding 10 to BallSprite every time it gets called. What exactly are you wanting to happen?

Comment: @Coder - you haven't taken any steps to clear the canvas. Therefore, your old image remains at the time the ball is drawn again in a different position. ;)